# Is it possible for HYPERLINK to spill friendly names?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of websites, with each row containing its name and URL. I'm trying to use the `HYPERLINK()` function to return these in a spilled dynamic array.

`=HYPERLINK(tblWebsites[URL],tblWebsites[Website])`

[image]

Unfortunately, using the `[friendly_name]` argument repeats the first entry, meaning it's displaying 'Google' three times, rather than 'Yahoo' and 'Bing' for the second and third values.

I don't want to use one formula per value, so is there some kind of obscure workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the @-notation when you use it inside the Excel Table as follow:

```
=HYPERLINK(@[URL],@[Website])
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Outside of the table, doesn't work because it seems `HYPERLINK` function doesn't accept for `friendly_name` input argument an array, but the link output is correct. For example the following works: `=HYPERLINK(tblWebsite[URL])`, but it doesn't show the friendly name. You can use `MAP` function to overcome it:

```
=MAP(tblWebsite[URL],tblWebsite[Name], LAMBDA(url,name, HYPERLINK(url, name)))
```

Here is the output in **E** column:
[image: Map output]

Comment: I was just going to post `MAP()` function. ^1 from me.

Comment: This only appears to work in Excel in the browser - if I use the desktop app (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20002) then _all_ 3 items in the spill range link to Google

Comment: @SpectralInstance I tested for Excel for Web free and also for Microsoft 365 for enterprise. Version 2305 (Build 16501.20196) for desktop application. Current channel. In both cases it works as expected. I could not test it for other versions. Excel version is a mess, and changes are not well communicated. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel) for the current channel but there is no an explicit mention to this function. As per your version number it is a newer one, but I don't find this update in the current channel update.

Comment: per my understanding @SpectralInstance your version belongs to [Beta Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/beta-channel)

Comment: The output is correct, but the links all point to the first URL in the list. Is there any way of overcoming this?

Comment: @Statto I tested in Excel Web (the free version) and it works, I could not test it in my desktop Excel, since the page is blocked by the proxy. Did you try in Excel in the browser? if this doesn't work some version, then the solution would be to implement something in Office Script or VBA.

Comment: Yes, it works in Excel for the Web. Unfortunately, it doesn't in the desktop version, though, and I'm on the Beta Channel. I hope this gets sorted out soon.

Comment: Try to send this feedback to Microsoft, maybe they can take into account.